# Wordpress <img width height /> Problems

Tags: images

```
<img loading=“lazy” src=“https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/news-coming-soon-small-box-01-150x150.jpg” width=“150” height=“150” alt="" title="" class=“img-responsive wp-image-5129” srcset=“example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/news-coming-soon-small-box-01-200x200.jpg 200w, …400x400.jpg 400w, …600x600.jpg 600w, …800x800.jpg 800w, …1200x1200.jpg 1200w, … 1625w” sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 400px" tmp_title="">
```

My issues are that when I upload an image by fusion builder image element, the image always always always is cut from original 1625w to 150w, and sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 400px", the max-width is 400px rather than 1625px. This issue causes the images so small on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a few default image sizes which are generated on every upload. These are:

```
150px square for thumbnails
300px width for medium images
768px max width for medium_large images
1024px max width for large images.
```

Fusion builder should have a setting to change the output image to a bigger size. Or, if you have access to the code, simply change it to:

```
<img loading=“lazy” src=“https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/news-coming-soon-small-box-01.jpg” alt="" title="" class=“img-responsive wp-image-5129” srcset=“example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/news-coming-soon-small-box-01-200x200.jpg 200w, …400x400.jpg 400w, …600x600.jpg 600w, …800x800.jpg 800w, …1200x1200.jpg 1200w, … 1625w” sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 400px" tmp_title="">
```